# Pessoal um problema que parece muito bobo sobre a conexão em PHP

Tags: php, funções, mysqli

Estou começando API básica para uso pessoal, mas no primeiro momento já me deparei com um probleminha que meus olhos não perceberam a origem:

> Warning: mysqli_connect() expects parameter 1 to be string, object given in

Aqui minha conexão:

```
<?php

function BDconecta() {

    $con = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", NULL, "emissor_nfe") or die("Sem conexão ".  mysqli_connect_error());
    mysqli_set_charset($con, "utf8");
    return $con;

}

function BDClose($con) {
    mysqli_close($con);
}
?>
```

E aqui onde chamo a conexão com o BD que aparece o erro:

```
<?php
include_once './conexao/conn.php';
if (!isset($_GET['pg'])) {
    echo '<h2>Escolha um Emitente para Começar:</h2><br/>';
    $query = ('Select * FROM emitente');
    $lista = mysqli_connect(BDconecta(), $query) or die("Um erro na comunicao" . mysqli_connect_error());
    $achou = mysqli_num_rows($lista);
    if ($achou > 0) {
        while ($exibir = mysqli_fetch_array($lista)) {
            $id = $exibir['id'];
            $fantasi = $exibir['nome_fantasia'];

            echo '<table><tr><td>' . $id . '</td><td>' . $fantasi . '</td></tr></table>';

        }
        echo '<br/><h2><a href="?pg=incluir">CADASTRAR</a></h2>';
    }else{
        echo '<h2 style="color: red">Nenhum Emitente Cadastrado</h2>';
        echo '<br/><h2><a href="?pg=incluir">CADASTRAR NOVO</a></h2>';
    }
} else {
    $pagina = $_GET['pg'];
    switch ($pagina) {
        case 'incluir';
            include_once './privado/cad_emitente.php';
            break;
        default:
    }
}
?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Isso não faz sentido:

```
$lista = mysqli_connect(BDconecta(), $query) or die("erro" . mysqli_connect_error());
```

Provavelmente você quer isso:

```
$con = BDconecta()
$lista = mysqli_query($con, $query) or die("Um erro na comunicao" . mysqli_error($con));
```

Manual:

> http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.mysqli-connect.php

> http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/mysqli.query.php

De qualquer forma, geralmente é péssima idéia usar a função diretamente na query, o normal seria armazenar em algum lugar, ou nem usar função, deixar o include aberto e usar o `$con` diretamente.

Perceba que eu precisei do `$con` novamente para recuperar o erro, na mesma linha.

Muito mais simples seria a conexão não ter a função, e fazer só isso:

```
<?php
   $con = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", NULL, "emissor_nfe")
      or die("Sem conexão ".  mysqli_connect_error());
```

E no código simplesmente usar o `$con` já obtido.